# How to ensure Spring Data JPA does not do DDLs (without Spring-Boot)?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following database config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mycompany.databaseutilities.repo")
@ImportResource("classpath:data_source.xml")
public class DataConfig {

   @Autowired
   DataSource dataSource;

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ans =
         new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      ans.setDataSource(dataSource);
      ans.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
      ans.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.databaseutilities.model");
      return ans;
   }

   @Bean
   public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter ans = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      ans.setShowSql(false);
      ans.setGenerateDdl(false); // is this sufficient?
      ans.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
      return ans;
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
      JpaTransactionManager ans = new JpaTransactionManager();
      ans.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

      return ans;
   }
}
```

Package `com.mycompany.databaseutilities.model` contains classes, annotated by `@Entity`

Can I be sure, that it won't execute any DDL statements? I don't wish to damage existing database.

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: Don't give DDL permissions to the application's db user/schema, and you're safe.

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal where to write this? I don't have any config files.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I need application to be able to DDL, I just don't need it to do this itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property in your spring boot `application.properties` or `application.yaml` file.

You can also specify this at the time of creating your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` by supplying properties:

```
final Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
jpaProperties.put( AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "false" );

entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties( jpaProperties );
```